# Visa fee for Swiss visa in London

Tags: schengen, switzerland, fees-and-charges, visa-free-entry, swiss

I am an Indian, residing in UK, planning to visit Switzerland. I see that [there](http://www.eda.admin.ch/eda/en/home/reps/eur/vgbr/rkclon/vsirlo/vislon.html) are two places in London where you can apply for the visa

1. VFS Application Center, The Battleship Building, 179 Harrow Road, London W2 6NB
2. Regional Consular Center, Embassy of Switzerland, 16-18 Montagu Place, 
   London W1H2BQ

Also I see from the [VFS site](http://www.vfsglobal.ch/switzerland/uk/visa_fees_at_glance.html) that, there is a VFS fee involved along with the visa fee. So my questions are:

1. If I go to Regional Consular Center (Which is not managed by VFS), do i need to pay the VFS fee?
2. Is there an option to pay the visa fee online?
3. Do they accept credit/debit card or do we need to carry cash?
4. I was told that if we are carry cash, we need to carry exact amount and they will never issue change back. Is that so?

Comment: 1)No 2)No, in person only 3) Cards and cash both fine, they will ask on how to pay. 4) They will give change back. And why don't you contact the embassy directly. They generally reply back immediately, from experience.

Answer (score 2):

I have mailed the Swiss embassy, updating the answer from their response (for posterity)

1. No need to pay the VFS fee, if applying at "Regional Consular Center". So we pay only £49. Nothing more.
2. No online payment option for "Regional Consular Center". VFS have an option to pay online.
3. "Regional Consular Center" accepts only cash. VFS has option to accept card.
4. We need to carry exact change.